# jvm.dll can't be loaded by ignite.jni.dll

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, java

I built Apache ignite 2.7.0 in 64-bit in MS VS2012.
When I launch it, I always get the error

> Unable to start program 'C:...\Lib\apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin\platforms\cpp\project\vs\x64\Debug\ignite.core.dll'

I checked it with Dependency Walker, but I get

> JVM.DLL can't be found.

Here is my Java setup:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212 Path=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

I put them both into "User variables" and "System variables".

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` is not a valid path entry. Path entries consist of directories ...

Comment: It's cool that JVM.DLL can be found, after I remove jvm.dll and leave path only. But there are still other DLL loading issues: 
IGNITE.CORE.DLL -> SHELL32.DLL -> WININET.DLL -> IERTUTIL.DLL:
In IERTUTIL.DLL, these three DLLs can't be loaded:
USERENV.DLL  
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL